# Versioning of ActiveX COM DLL with Semantic Versioning but GUID per MAJOR.MINOR?

Tags: dll, com, versioning, semantic-versioning

Long story short, I'm the maintainer of a VisualBasic 6 project that products an ActiveX COM DLL that is used internally by ~50 other software packages that have internal uses in the organization.

For the last couple years we have been following the Semantic Versioning "MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH" for each DLL released and have been assigning a unique GUID per release. i.e. 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 have separate GUIDs.

It has worked OK, but this causes each of the software packages to require a new release -- even when none are needed -- just so they can reference the new GUID and recompile. This wastes a few dozen man hours due to internal processes for releases.

My question is, would it be a "bad practice" to maintain a GUID for each MINOR release so that 1.1.1, 1.1.2, and even 1.1.99 would have the same GUID? Would it be better to do a GUID per Major release instead?

This would cause references to only change when a new Major or Minor release is made reducing the number of changes required to software packages that depend on it.

Lastly, if it helps with the response, currently the DLLS are named as: MyActiveXDLL_vMAJOR.MINOR.PATCH.dll.

With a GUID per MINOR we would switch to MyActiveXDLL_vMAJOR.MINOR.dll

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this by not changing the GUID (you can set it in Class Builder, and it is stored in hidden attributes you can see if you open the source file in Notepad), but you can only do this if you aren't making any breaking changes.

Breaking changes are:

- Interface changes (added/changed/removed/re-ordered methods/properties)

  - Includes changes to dispids, parameter orders, parameter names
- Removed interfaces
- Methods which worked before but don't now. (only a problem if the method is used. If no longer used, you can deprecate it and just have it throw an error, but not get rid of it).

In VB by default you will be relying on the auto-generated dispids, guids and interfaces. You can set these to particular values using the Class Builder.

- Class Builder is this thing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa442930(v=vs.60).aspx

You can set the initial values to the auto-generated values in the previous release. You have to do this by hand - you will have to open the type library in TLBVIEW to find out what they are.

Comment: I've previously used Binary Compatibility with a previously compiled DLL to maintain GUIDs. As long as existing interfaces don't change the GUIDs won't change. It also allows new interfaces to be added without the GUID changing. Would this be a good practice to start using, assuming there are no breaking changes? Would it be better to have a guid per MAJOR or per MAJOR.MINOR release?

Comment: @robodude666  If you use binary compatibility, it really doesn't matter what you do with the version numbers. Provided you don't introduce breaking changes, and the version number increases, it doesn't make any difference. It's just a matter of style.